# getting number of days between twoo dates

Tags: django, django-views

I don't figure out how to get the number of days betwen twoo dates:
this is the models I have :

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    """A typical class defining a reservation model."""

    # Fields
    id_reservation = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    client_id = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chambre_id = models.ForeignKey(Chamber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Metadata
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-end_date']

    # Methods
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular instance of MyModelName."""
        return reverse('model-detail-view', args=[str(self.id_reservation)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id_reservation
```

and try to calculate the days between the end_date and the start_date in my generic view:

```
class ReservationsListView(generic.ListView):
    """ReservationsListView: produce a list of all Reservations """
    model = Reservation

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['periode'] = Reservation.end_date-Reservation.start_date
        return context
```

can please help doing this.

Comment: This will not work, since `Reservation` is the `Reservation` model.

Comment: I want to display the totale price, for that I need the totale period to calculate the price by multiplying it by the night price. how can I get it if not from the model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract the two `date` objects, and then obtain the `.days` attribute, so:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    # …
    
    @property
    def days(self):
        return (self.end_date - self.start_date).days
```

This will thus return the difference in days, so that means that if we calculate the difference between today and yesterday, this will result in one day:

```
>>> (date(2021, 4, 28) - date(2021, 4, 27)).days
1
```

If you want to take both days into account, you increment the result with 1:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    # …
    
    @property
    def days(self):
        return (self.end_date - self.start_date).days + 1
```

You can thus retrieve the number of days from a `Reservation` *object* with:

```
my_reservation.days
```